# How to pass values into an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a php code as shown below in which the values **(let us supposed I entered 12, 13, 14)** of `$data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}` is coming through admin portal. 
Let us suppose I have entered **12, 13, 14** for `"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE`

**Php code:**

```
'post__in' => array($data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}),
```

On debug it is returning:

```
[post__in] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12, 13, 14
    )
```

Whereas I want to be returned like this:

```
[post__in] => Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 14
)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that its return in the way I want.

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode or preg_split.

Explode is static and must have both comma and space.

```
'post__in' => explode(", ",$data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}),
```

Preg_split can have an optional space, meaning it can split strings like `"12,13,14"` and `"12, 13, 14"` and even `"12,        13,   14"` which explode can't.

```
'post__in' => preg_split("/,\s*/",$data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}),
```

If it's user input you need to split then I would definitely go for preg_split.
It's very common for "normal" people (not programmers) to write numbers with space in-between.

Comment: Nice spot suggesting regex

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks! It was the "post_in" that made me think it's user input.

Comment: @Andreas I have one more question. Its not similar. I am wondering if you can give me some pointer.

Comment: yes, I am able to pull specific content from xml. I just want to integrate with the current code

Comment: @Andreas No worries, thanks for the help in this question.

Comment: @Andreas Hi, I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192780/how-to-check-if-a-date-falls-between-two-days-of-a-week). Its not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 2):

If the value of `$data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}` is a comma-separated string, you should [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it:

```
'post__in' => explode(",", $data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'post__in' => explode(',', $data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too:

```
'post__in' => str_getcsv($data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE}),
```

> **str_getcsv** — Parse a CSV string into an array
>
> **str_getcsv(** *string* **$input**,*string* **$delimiter**=",",*string* **$enclosure**='"',*string* **$escape**="\" **)** :*array*
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Then if it has `,\s` you can trim using array map.

```
'post__in' => array_map('trim', str_getcsv($data->{"articles_id_" . ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE})),
```

In this case it's similar to `explode` or `preg_split`, but those were taken already as answers ... :-p

This treats it more like a CSV line so it will deal with things like this `foo,"Some other thing",bar` - Some CSV formats (includng PHP `fputcsv` and `SplFileObject::fputcsv` will enclose strings with spaces or commas with double quotes `"`.  Explode/Preg Split would retain the `"` but this would remove them. It also does a few other things that are CSV related. But as I said, in this case with integers it's basically the same as `explode(',', ...)`

Cheers!

Comment: Multiexplode is still not taken as an answer. I think a multiexplode and array_filter will do the same thing as str_getcsv and trim.